# how to query (filter) documents from firebase to flutter app based on a value nested in a List of Maps?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to get documents from my 'Patients' Collection which contain an array of maps 'Appointments' based on the value of 'translator' key as shown here:

[image]

here is how im trying to query the documents but i guess im having a syntax error

```
  static Stream<QuerySnapshot> getSpecificUserAppointments(String translatorName) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Patients')
        .where('appointments', arrayContains: translatorName)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

i also tried to filter this way

```
 .where('appointments.translator', arrayContains: translatorName), 
 .where('appointments.translator', isEqualto: translatorName)
```

still not getting results

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arrayContains` operator checks whether the exact, complete item you specify exists in the array. So your check would only work if the `appointments` array contained an entry that has a single string as its value with `translatorName`.

If you want to check whether a certain name exists, add an additional array field to your document with `translatorNames`, where you keep just the (unique) names of the translators in the document. Then you can use that field to query:

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Patients')
    .where('translatorNames', arrayContains: translatorName)
    .snapshots();
```

Comment: so with the current structure of my documents i cant get the value i need through this way of filtering and i have to add another field which contains the value i need right ? the reason im doing this is to get the number of appointments each translator has by getting the query results.length

Comment: Getting an unpredictable number of documents to determine only that count is wasteful (both of bandwidth and money), so I'd recommend at storing that count for each translator explicitly in the database and updating it on every write.

Comment: thanks i will consider your recommendation :)